# How to get total sum of every 10 record using php

Tags: php, loops

for example:

10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
9

OUTPUT

10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
`-----
100

next loop

10
9
`---
19

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to do using `array_chunk` and `array_sum`

```
$arr=array(
    10,10,9,10,8,10,7,10,15,10,12,11,10,9,5,21,25,10,15,14,18,12,0,1,2,
    13,18,18,18,12,0,1,2,4,5,25,10,7,10,15,10,12,11,10,9,5,21,25,10,15,
    14,13,18,18,18,12,0,1,2,4,5,25,10,7,10,15,10,12,11,10,9,5,21,25,10,
    15,14,13,18,18,4,5,25,18,12,0,1,2,4,5,25,10,7,10,9,10,8,10,7,10,15
);
$size=10;

foreach( array_chunk( $arr, $size ) as $chunk ){
    printf('%d<br />', array_sum( $chunk ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) and [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php).

Array_splice cuts out part of the input array and array_sum sums the part.

```
$arr = range(1,100); // your array
$size = 10;

for($i=0; $i<count($arr)/$size;){
    echo array_sum(array_splice($arr,0,$size)) ."\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/8u00c

Edit; now that I think about it, you don't need the `/$size` in the loop.
The loop works just as good with:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($arr);){
    echo array_sum(array_splice($arr,0,$size)) ."\n";
}
```

Because as long as there is values in $arr it will keep looping and suming values.